# Define widget key bindings

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, widget

The following code:

1. defines a major mode `my-mode` where `C-d` binding is redefined;
2. opens a `my-mode` buffer inserting an editable-field widget.

```
(require 'widget)
(require 'wid-edit)

;; Define my-mode mode
(defvar my-mode-map
  (let ((map widget-keymap))
    (define-key map (kbd "C-d") (lambda () (interactive) (message "Ctrl D")))
    map))
(define-derived-mode my-mode nil "My")


;; Open my-mode buffer and insert editable field
(let ((buf (get-buffer-create "*buf*")))
  (with-current-buffer buf
    (my-mode)
    (widget-create 'editable-field
           :format "Field 1: %v ")
    (widget-setup))
  (switch-to-buffer buf))
```

My problem is that, `C-d` binding works only outside the editable field.
How can I make it work inside the field too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `C-d` in the keymap passed through the `:keymap` property of the widget.
As a test you can use:

```el
(widget-create 'editable-field
           :format "Field 1: %v "
           :keymap my-mode-map)
```

Note that the default value for `:keymap` is not the value of `widget-keymap` but `widget-field-keymap` (if that is what you were after). Nevertheless, changing the value of `widget-field-keymap` does not help since the value of `widget-field-keymap` is already used in `widget-define` at load-time of the library `widget`.

Maybe you should use a modified copy of `widget-field-keymap` for the widget to have the standard bindings defined in the editable field.
Something like that:

```el
(progn
  (switch-to-buffer (get-buffer-create "*buf*"))
  (let ((my-widget-field-keymap (copy-keymap widget-field-keymap)))
    (define-key my-widget-field-keymap (kbd "C-d") (lambda () (interactive) (message "Ctrl D")))
    (widget-create 'editable-field
           :keymap my-widget-field-keymap
           :format "Field 1: %v ")
    (widget-setup)))
```

See also the [widget documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/widget.html#Basic-Types).